# Send parameters in URL more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Now i need to call mvc action by using URL and send parameters to this action in URL this action take parameters and insert row in Database ..... but i found strange issue in that when i call this function by its URL in azure ,Sometimes the function called twice or three or four times  although i enter URL one time and sometimes the function executed one time when i called it by URL . I'm sure that the function is right and this function is n't recursion function and hasn't go to ...But in my Local machine when i call this function by URL it's executed one time always so i couldn't generate this issue local to trace it and know the reason of this issue ...So I suspect the browser may call function more than once when i enter URL .... i searched about problem like my problem but i didn't find any thing so if some one see some thing like my issue and know the reason i wish to tell me and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Despite your certainty to the correctness of your calling function, have you perhaps tried inserting a breakpoint to see if it is called multiple times over the course of execution? Seems like that could be the simplest place to start.

Comment: Yes i inserted breakpoint but i couldn't to generate this issue local the function called one time but i azure when i enter the URL the function is called one time or more than that !

Comment: it's clear that my issue is so difficult cuz no one reply till now :( :( :(

Comment: It's more difficult because you've given very little to go off of. By your description, when you call an MVC action hosted on Azure via its URL, sometimes it executes more than once. You've given no code to show how you're calling it (possibility), no code to show what happens when it's called (possibility) and give very little support information with which someone could attempt to help out with to identify your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, GET actions should never modify database, use POST actions for that.

Second, your issue may be caused by browser page preloading feature (Google Chrome has that for sure). To be sure try another browser and see what happens.
Also, try to write a simple program that will do a GET request (using WebClient class). That may help you better understand what is happening.

Comment: thanks @eldarien for your reply but what did you mean about browser page preloading feature (Google Chrome has that for sure) ?!

Comment: when i use another browser the function called one time

Comment: @NOOR This one: http://readwrite.com/2012/01/05/new_chrome_will_load_web_pages_before_you_hit_ente